# Android Studio Kotlin Boolean.Companion problem

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In my code i want to execute holder.task.setChecked() command with item.getStatus()) as a parameter.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = data[position]
    holder.task.text = item.getTask()
    holder.task.setChecked(item.getStatus())
}
```

The problem is that setChecked requires type **Boolean**, but from getStatus function i get **Boolean.Companion** in return.

```
class Model(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
private var id = Int
private var status = Boolean
private var task = String

fun getStatus(): Boolean.Companion {
       return status
}
```

When i try to change the return type of this function, i get thrown with an error.

Been thinking for a while about how to change the types to be equal, but i cannot seem to find the solution.

To be clear, setChecked function is a default function which im executing on **Checkbox** object

Comment: paste the fun setChecked to check the code

Comment: sorry, could you write what do you mean in more details?

Comment: @deja, you said you get an error. Please provide the error message and full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: it's a missmatch error, both when i try to execute the function or change the getStatus's return type to Boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is very unusual, and I'm not sure you actually meant to do what you're doing here.

This for example

```
private var id = Int
```

**doesn't** hold an `Int`. `id` is not a number. It's actually the *companion object* for the `Int` class, which in this case holds the constants `MAX_VALUE`, `MIN_VALUE`, `SIZE_BYTES` and `SIZE_BITS`. Usually you'd access these directly on the `Int` class, like `Int.MAX_VALUE` - when you do that you're actually accessing them on the companion object, which is why assigning the value `Int` to a variable *gives you that companion object*.

So the same goes for `var status = Boolean` - it's `Boolean`'s *companion object*. And that's why your function has to return `Boolean.Companion`, because it's returning `status`, and that's what `status` **is**. It's **not** a boolean value of *true* or *false*.

---

There may be reasons why you'd want to do this - it's very unlikely though, and the way you're trying to use this (wanting a `Boolean` from `getStatus`) suggests that this is a mistake, and you're not familiar with the language. I'd *really* recommend [running through the basic intro stuff](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html) to get a feel for how you define variables and their types, but this is probably what you wanted:

```
class Model(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private var id: Int = -1
    private var status: Boolean = false
    private var task: String = ""

    fun getStatus(): Boolean {
        return status
    }
}
```

I've added default values to each because *you have to initialise them to something* - if you have an `init` block where that happens, you can omit the values. If you're assigning them right there, you can omit the types too (e.g. `var id = -1`) unless you need to be more specific than the value is (e.g. if you want it to be a nullable `Int?` type).

You could also put these values in the constructor:

```
class Model(
    itemView: View,
    private var id: Int,
    private var status: Boolean,
    private var task: String
)
```

which would require the caller to provide some initial values. It depends what you want!

If you wanted, you could also replace the getter function by doing this:

```
var status: Boolean = false
    private set
```

which makes the `status` property public, but read-only from the outside.

---

And just FYI, your `Model` class looks like your *data* for your `RecyclerView`'s Adapter - it **should not** be a `ViewHolder`, those are completely separate things. Just use a basic class for your `Model` (or even better, a `data class`) and use that in your data list.

`ViewHolder`s are special objects that get reused to display different data items - and by definition there's usually more data items than there are `ViewHolder`s (that's the whole point of a `RecyclerView` - it *recycles* them). You shouldn't be keeping them in a list, or storing individual items' state in them.

Keep your data items in a list, fetch the one at `position` in `onBindViewHolder`, then display it in the `ViewHolder` you're provided with. What you have right now isn't going to work, so you'll need to look at a tutorial for setting one up, e.g. [this one from the docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview). You need to store references to the `View`s you're using in the VH, like a `TextView` and a `Checkbox`, so you can do things like

`holder.taskTextView.text = item.getTask()`

Comment: really helped me with this one, great job :)

Answer (score 1):

The `setChecked` function requires a `Boolean` param, but the return type of `getStatus` is `Boolean.Companion`. This is because you have defined the `status` field as of `Boolean.Companion` type.

To fix this, you may define `status` as a normal class level field and either assign a default value, or provide a constructor to initialize the value appropriately.

```
private var status: Boolean = false // or true, depending on the default value that suits here
```

Then you can change the `getStatus` function to return a `Boolean` type instead of `Boolean.Companion`

```
fun getStatus(): Boolean {
    return status
}
```

and then use it to call `holder.task.setChecked(item.getStatus())`.